# call resolver function one more time

Tags: angular2-routing, angular-resolver

in routing I have next:
`{path: 'modules', component: ..., resolve: { modules: ModulesServiceResolver},
{path: 'modules/:id', component: ...}`

and when I return back from child component - resolve not called one more time?

array of modules, which I get from modules resolver can be changed when I am in inner page. I want to get them?

how to call resolver one more time when return from child route?

UPD: 
modules I have done as separate module
then in `modules.routing` done next 
`{
    path: '',
    component: ModulesComponent,
    resolve: {
        projects: ModulesService
    },
    runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'
  },
  {
    path: ':id',
    loadChildren: () => import('./module/module.module').then(m => m.ModuleModule)
  }`

now works as needed

Answer (score 0):

modules I have done as separate module then in modules.routing done next `{
    path: '',
    component: ModulesComponent,
    resolve: {
        projects: ModulesService
    },
    runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'
  },
  {
    path: ':id',
    loadChildren: () => import('./module/module.module').then(m => m.ModuleModule)
  }`